# Return zero with Count and GroupBy

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query with groupby and count but I cant have the lines where the count(*) gives 0.

code :

```
SELECT 
    e.sexe as sex, count(*) as number, n.id_niveau as niv

FROM
      fact_resultat f, dim_etudiant e, dim_niveau n 


 WHERE
        f.id_etudiant = e.id_etudiant AND f.id_niveau = n.id_niveau AND
        resultat = 'Non Admis' AND etape = '1'
            AND filiere = 'API'
    GROUP BY sexe , niv
```

how can i make it return the lines with 0 count ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You said "I can't have the lines where the count is 0" and "how can i make it return the lines with 0". In my mind, these mean "I don't want any 0 count lines" and "I only want 0 count lines". Could you please state more accurately what it is you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

One possible solution is to just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT e.sexe as sex, n.id_niveau as niv
       sum(resultat = 'Non Admis' AND etape = '1' AND filiere = 'API') as number,
FROM fact_resultat f JOIN
     dim_etudiant e
     ON f.id_etudiant = e.id_etudiant JOIN
     dim_niveau n 
     ON f.id_niveau = n.id_niveau
GROUP BY sexe, niv;
```

It is also possible that you need outer joins -- depending on what you mean by the rows with zero count.

Comment: but now I don't get the count by sex I get 4 lines when i should have just two

Answer (score 0):

If you only want lines where the count is 0, add this to the end of your sql:

```
HAVING count(*) = 0
```

If you don't want lines with 0, make it

```
HAVING count(*) > 0
```

I really don't know how you'd get a zero count with that query anyway, because it doesn't use outer joins and it doesn't count any columns that would be null.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the IFNULL() function

```
SELECT e.sexe as sex,
       IFNULL(count(*),0) as number, 
       n.id_niveau as niv
...
```

or use COALESCE() function

```
SELECT e.sexe as sex,
       COALESCE(count(*),0) as number, 
       n.id_niveau as niv
```